# pass external variable to a field in popup: (arcgis-js-api)

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api

Here is my code in which I am setting and calling a popup in arcgis-js-api (4.xx) via one rest call... the problem I have an external variable I would like to populate within the field 'place' this external variable doesn't come from the same rest call, I have the value, not sure why it won't accept it in the field?

```
var place = 'something cool x';
........
   var popuptemp = {
          title: "Shake Intensity",
          content: [{
            type: "fields",
            fieldInfos: [{
                fieldName: "grid_value",
                label: "Grid Value"
              },
              {
                fieldName: "id",
                label: "id"
              },
              {
                fieldName: "place",
                label: "place"
              },
              {
                fieldName: "ObjectID",
                label: "ObjectID"
              },
              {
                fieldName: "url",
                label: "Url"
              }
            ]
          }]
        }

        fl = new FeatureLayer({
          source: gras,
          objectIdField: "ObjectID",
          geometryType: "polygon",
          fields: [{
            name: "ObjectID",
            alias: "ObjectID",
            type: "oid"
          }, {
            name: "id",
            alias: "id",
            type: "string"
          }, {
            name: place <--------------------- tried just calling the var here with no avail, no errors, just nothing displays
            alias: "place",
            type: "string"
          }, {
            name: "url",
            alias: "url",
            type: "string"
          }, {
            name: "grid_value",
            alias: "grid_value",
            type: "double"
          }],
          renderer: renderer,
          popupEnabled: true,
          popupTemplate: popuptemp
        });

        map.add(fl);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to add external data like a field. But you could use a function to define the content. Take a look at this example that I made for you, in there `author` is the global value.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>ArcGIS API for JavaScript Hello World App</title>
  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #viewDiv {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .disclaimer {
      font-size: 14px;
      font-style: italic;
      color: white;
      background-color: black;
    }
  </style>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.15/esri/css/main.css">
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.15/"></script>

  <script>
    require([
      'esri/Map',
      'esri/views/MapView',
      'esri/layers/FeatureLayer'
    ], function (Map, MapView, FeatureLayer) {

      let author = 'by @cabesuon';

      const map = new Map({
        basemap: 'streets-navigation-vector'
      });

      const view = new MapView({
        container: 'viewDiv',
        map: map,
        zoom: 12,
        center: {
          latitude: 32.7353,
          longitude: -117.1490
        }
      });

      function toGraphic(lon, lat, ObjectID, title, addrs, url) {
        return {
          geometry: {
            type: 'point',
            longitude: lon,
            latitude: lat
          },
          attributes: {
            ObjectID,
            title,
            addrs,
            url
          }
        }
      }
      
      const graphics = [
        toGraphic(
          -117.1560632,
          32.727482,
          1,
          'Automotive Museum',
          '2080 Pan American Plaza, San Diego, CA 92101, United States',
          'http://sdautomuseum.org/'
        ),
        toGraphic(
          -117.1763293,
          32.7136902,
          2,
          'USS Midway Museum',
          '910 N Harbor Dr, San Diego, CA 92101, United States',
          'http://www.midway.org/'
        ),
        toGraphic(
          -117.2284536,
          32.7641112,
          3,
          'SeaWorld',
          '500 Sea World Dr, San Diego, CA 92109, United States',
          'https://seaworld.com/san-diego'
        ),
        toGraphic(
          -117.1557741,
          32.7360032,
          4,
          'Zoo',
          '2920 Zoo Dr, San Diego, CA 92101, United States',
          'https://zoo.sandiegozoo.org/'
        )
      ];

      function popupContent (feature) {
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML =
        `Address: ${feature.graphic.attributes.addrs}<br>` +
        `<a href='${feature.graphic.attributes.url}'>${feature.graphic.attributes.url}</a><br><br>` +
        `<span class="disclaimer">${author}</span>`;
        return div;
      }

      const layer = new FeatureLayer({
        source: graphics,
        fields: [
          {
            name: 'ObjectID',
            alias: 'ObjectID',
            type: 'oid'
          }, {
            name: 'title',
            alias: 'title',
            type: 'string'
          }, {
            name: 'addrs',
            alias: 'addrs',
            type: 'string'
          }, {
            name: 'url',
            alias: 'url',
            type: 'string'
          }
        ],
        objectIDField: ['ObjectID'],
        geometryType: 'point',
        renderer: {
          type: 'simple',
          symbol: {
            type: 'text',
            color: 'red',
            text: '\ue61d',
            font: {
              size: 30,
              family: 'CalciteWebCoreIcons'
            }
          }
        },
        popupTemplate: {
          title: '{title}',
          content: popupContent,
          outFields: ['*']
        }
      });
      
      map.add(layer);

    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for this; so could I define two 'content:' fields? I want to continue to add the fields which I had already working, but just add one custom item from a different rest call? do I simply add another content property i.e.  'content: customFunction,' under the content: with my fields?

Comment: or I have to redefine the whole things feeding the other standard fields into the next context as well?

Comment: anyway to pass it in without redefining the whole thing for others as well?

Comment: What is not working in the pen? ... Which variable are you trying to show that it doesn't?

Comment: Hey, I got that part - onto a new challege now; I am trying to write innerHTML inside the popup template title

Comment: Any idea in regards to title?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62819295/add-innerhtml-within-title-of-popuptemplate-arcgis-js-api